# Cant push_back() non copyable object to vector reference C++

Tags: c++, vector, reference, unique-ptr

I am having some trouble with a tiny piece of code that has me a little confused. I am currently working on a project where speed is important, hence my choice of c++.

I am trying to pass a vector into a function by reference. The vector is of type `unique_ptr<int>` and I would like to call `push_back()` on the vector to add elements to it. I have made sure that I am calling `move()` on the pointer when I pass it into `push_back()` but for some reason I get compiler errors telling me that:

```
static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
```

This only happens when I pass the vector by reference, rather than by value. I could pass the vector by value, but I would like to avoid unnecessary copying if possible. This error doesnt seem to happen when trying to add copyable objects to either the vector passed by value or reference.

Im using g++ 9.3.0 to compile.

Here is a little snippet that reproduces the error, any help appreciated.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void appendToVectorVal(vector<unique_ptr<int>> vectorVal){
    unique_ptr<int> toPush = make_unique<int>(1);
    vectorVal.push_back(move(toPush)); // does compile
}

void appendToVectorRef(vector<unique_ptr<int>>& vectorRef){
    unique_ptr<int> toPush = make_unique<int>(1);
    vectorRef.push_back(move(toPush)); // doesnt compile
}

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> ptrVector;
    appendToVectorVal(ptrVector);
    appendToVectorRef(ptrVector);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what about `emplace` ?

Comment: *"I could pass the vector by value"* -- you sure about that? Passing by value means making a copy of the vector, which entails making a copy of the `unique_ptr`, which is a no-go (and is in fact the only error I got when trying to compile your code).

Comment: If I comment out the line `appendToVectorVal(ptrVector);`, your code compiles for me. Are you misinterpreting what your compiler is telling you? Could you provide more lines of error messages (i.e. more context) from your compiler?

Comment: @JaMiT you are right I have incorrectly written the problem out. push_back() does work when the vector is a local variable and there is no copying involved. I am just misinterpreting my errors entirely. My bad, will close the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet fails to compile simply because you are passing a vector of `unique_ptr` by value to the `appendToVectorVal` function. passing a vector by value means you call the copy constructor of `std::vector`, which call the constructor of every element the vector holds. But the copy constructor of `std::unique_ptr` is deleted.

In fact the following snippet compiles successfully:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

void appendToVectorRef(vector<unique_ptr<int>>& vectorRef){
    unique_ptr<int> toPush = make_unique<int>(1);
    vectorRef.push_back(move(toPush));
}

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<int>> ptrVector;
    appendToVectorRef(ptrVector);
    return 0;
}
```

Applying `push_back` with a moved object is valid. It calls the `void push_back( T&& value );` version (In C++20 qualified with a `constexpr`), which only require `T` to be move constructible.